# Unable to read localized key value from Resource file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, localization

I am working on .NET Core Web API localization and I have done all configurations but I am unable to get local specific values.

1. Created 3 resource files for de-DE, fr-FR and English languages.
2. Created a common Middleware to set the current culture based on the
   query string value.
3. Trying to get the respective local key but it is always giving English value.

Can anyone suggest and tell did I miss anything in the configuration.

**Middleware**

```
namespace i18n
{
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

/// <summary>
/// The LocalizationMiddleware class.
/// </summary>
public class LocalizationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="LocalizationMiddleware"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="next">The next.</param>
    public LocalizationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invokes the specified context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    /// <returns>Task.</returns>
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var localValue = "en-US";
        if (context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("locale"))
        {
            localValue = context.Request.Query["locale"];
        }

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(localValue);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(localValue);

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The LocalizationMiddlewareExtensions class.
/// </summary>
public static class LocalizationMiddlewareExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Uses the localization middleware.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="builder">The builder.</param>
    /// <returns>The ApplicationBuilder.</returns>
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseLocalizationMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<LocalizationMiddleware>();
    }
} }
```

**Startup class**

I have registered the Middleware.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseLocalizationMiddleware();
    }
```

**Web API Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        var name = Employees.Name; // Always Name is coming english value
        return new string[] { name };
    }
```

This is my solution structure:

[image]

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56123547/how-to-read-resource-key-and-values-based-on-the-culture/56124362#56124362)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read Resource key and values based on the culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56123547/how-to-read-resource-key-and-values-based-on-the-culture)

Comment: No, I was trying diff approaches. Here Directly I am setting culture value to the current thread and reading the values. In the former one, I am using .NET core inbuilt functionality.